RAW, can you use Equipment Trait Rules on Removable Powers?
Generally speaking, devices are powers with the Removable flaw applied to them... but what kind of device that is seems to not come up much. Vehicles and Headquarters have listed 'traits' that can be increased as part of the nature of the device itself, such as Size, Toughness, Speed for Vehicles, Features, etc. (pg. 221 & 226).
If I get a Power with Removable, could I for example enhance the traits of the device itself to make it bigger, increase its toughness, link Speed and other Features that otherwise couldn't be linked to instant duration powers? I've yet to see someone do this, potentially making a Shield via increased size for half cover, or a Damage Power linked to Speed as a result of Removable. I know you can do something similar with Homing and Triggered Effect linking with Senses with a different duration as a result, but the issue I'm currently having is that Removable Flaw itself doesn't specify rules for picking a particular type of Equipment to use rules for, but then again Devices Rules (pg. 209) doesn't specify either.

Can you explain what you mean by "Equipment Trait Rules"? Are you asking if you can find a way to stack equipment with powers? Or whether it's possible to stack Removable powers with other powers?

For example Vehicles have "Traits" that you can increase such as speed, size, and toughness listed as I've said in the post. Headquarters has its own Traits and such that modify and increase the stats of the Device itself, rather than specifically the power(s) the device have. I even posted links to pg 221 and 226 that lead you to where they list. Think Damage 8 (Device Speed +8, Device Toughness +8, Device Size +3) (Removable)

Ah. I indeed misunderstood exactly what you meant. Thank you for the clarification.

TL;DR, no
The short answer is that no, there is no provision in 3E to use the vehicle or headquarters traits on Removeable powers, aka Devices. Those two items are specific sorts of equipment, meant for respectively equipment which are intended for movement and not moving at all. To quote from Gadget Guides Installations:

An installation is a permanent, fixed structure of some sort.
The simplest installation may be a stone cottage or tower,
while highly advanced installations can be orbiting satellites or vast underground complexes. The Hero’s Handbook
uses the term “headquarters,” but this Guide uses installation to cover all types of permanent structures, whether
they are used as headquarters, lairs, or what have you.
The key descriptors of an installation are permanent and
fixed. A tent or other temporary shelter is more equipment
than an installation, while something capable of moving
under its own power (rather than drifting on currents or in
a fixed orbit) is a vehicle rather than an installation (see Vehicles for more information). Installations may be moved
from place to place (see Movable under Installation Features, following) but this is usually an involved process,
rather than the mobility of a vehicle.
Unlike more complex items like vehicles, installations have
fairly few traits: just their size (starting at small), Toughness
(starting at rank 6) and whatever Features or powers the installation is given. Note that installation size is measured on
a separate scale, given on the Installation Size Categories
table....

The Gadget Guides Vehicles entry pretty much specifies the same thing, but in reverse, indicating that the primary aspect of vehicles is moving around in them, and they have size and traits appropriate to that. That is not to say that they don't have some overlaps. Installations includes a feature to allow an Installation to be moved. Vehicles suggests that some Headquarters features might be appropriate, such as creating an RV that has sleeping quarters, or a mobile lab. But otherwise, nothing in the rules indicates that these "Equipment traits" can be used outside of their specific section. Device size generally get handwaved by things like Subtle (to model small pieces of equipment that are easier to hide), Feature/Quirk (much like Subtle, indicating that the size of something has some measurable benefit or drawback), or Complications (when the GM decides that your Zweihander buster sword isn't going to fit through the air ducts, you might get a Hero Point for the situation, maybe not if it's an Equipment weapon).
But what about Gimmick's Guide?
So long as you don't mind going back two editions, and about nineteen years, Gimmick's Guide to Gadgets for 1E M&M does have rules for device size, essentially charging you points to make things smaller (which also makes them much easier to hide and harder to target) or refunds points for larger objects (which are harder to get around and offer penalties for using as weapons). It also adds a handful of Extras and Flaws to model things like especially tough or fragile devices.
But what if I'm the GM? Or I can convince the GM?
Congratulations, Rule 0 applies. There's nothing saying that your game can't decide to use these "Equipment Traits" as is to have an immobile gun emplacement, a computer big enough that you need the team brute to haul it around and you can use it for cover, or a set of sunglasses which are oddly hard to destroy (but not Indestructible), so long as the GM approves and it makes the game more fun for everyone.

So you can only use Enhanced Trait to modify their already existing traits, I suppose its good that they can't be applied as Devices since otherwise you could make them Indestructible Complete Cover Vehicles, but then again you can always use Transform's "altering their shape or material" with "Equipment has Toughness based on its Material to make your Vehicle Titanium (15 Toughness) or a Super Alloy (20+ Toughness)...if Devices and Equipment have mass...which by book they don't have any listed mass...in which case Transform doesn't work for its intended purpose....hm.

Its crazy there's no mention of mass in the gadget's guide, and even further beyond the only particular mentions of size is just that mecha are supposed to have them with via permanent enlarge. Throwing mentions a "10 ton truck" but there's no reference as to why or how its at that mass through game mechanics.

@FriendlyNeighborhoodChicken Sounds like you're in a good position to create your own set of house rules for it, whether it's detailed or simple (say, simply allowing your players to define a weight with a 1 pp Feature, subject to your approval). M&M is not a simulationist game, to say the least.

Best thing I've found thus far is simply using a structure's volume rank as mass rank, as per created object rules (given there really isn't a reason to use it in a different way). Growth also has something of a scaling property where mass rank +4 = size rank +1, but then again most humans are size rank 0 mass rank 2 so I figure perhaps there's a initial modifier to mass depending on your substance/material. I will probably make a compilation of the rules then ask on monday if there's anything in other books.
